# Kibana 5 Embdedding visualizations in webapp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am pretty new to Kibana 5 and ES 5. I am trying to embed the kibana visualizations in the custom web application.
I could like to add custom filter option available to endusers to filter the data. Is that option available in Kiabana 5?

Answer (score 0):

Kibana is mainly an internal administration tool. You can embed iframes from Kibana into your application, but that's about it.

People commonly use a visualization library (like D3.js), pull the data from Elasticsearch, and do their own visualizations in their application.